# In which library is readline() located?

Tags: c

I have been making a small personal project in C that involves the developer command prompt.
VS Code showed no issues, but when I attempted to compile the C file, I received the error message "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"
The unresolved external is "_readline"
I assumed that the only readline() I used was under one of the libraries I already included in the file.

Now I have no idea how to get this code to work.

Comment: There is no `readline()` in the C standard library, so the first question to consider is which `readline()` you are trying to use.  GNU's maybe?

Comment: The `readline` function comes from the `readline` library, which is commonly installed on all Linux systems. Might exist a Windows port, but you need to look for it.

Comment: Try `man 3 readline`